# Debugar function dentro de um package

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Tenho uma package com várias functions e procs. Como eu faço, usando o pl/sql developer, para debugar? Gostaria de saber como eu faço para ir até o erro e ver o que está sendo passado.

Usando a ferramenta Tests do pl/sql eu sei que eu consigo debugar. O que passa é que a function está dentro de uma package e gostaria de saber como eu faço isso, debugando, vendo o valor das variáveis e etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o commando:

```sql
ALTER PACKAGE PKG_NOME COMPILE DEBUG;
```

Isso fará que seja possível debugar sua *package*.

Então em *SQLWindow* clique com o direito em sua package,
e selecione: "*Edig Spec & Body*", então coloque os *break points* onde
deseja testar então execute seu teste em um "*Test Window*", como exemplo:

```sql
declare
  result boolean;
begin
  result := PKG_NOME.F_NOME('PRIMEIROPARAMETRO','SEGUNDOPARAMETRO');
  :result := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(result);
end;
```

Além dessa opção dentro do "*Edig Spec & Body*", vá até a segunda aba e localiza sua função clique direito e selecione *Test*, que terá o mesmo efeito.